# replacing german umlauts on macos

Tags: python-3.x, macos, replace, encoding, clipboard

I want to relplace german umlauts from a copyied file (Command + C in finder on the selected file). E.g. 'ästhetik.png' shall be 'aesthetik.png'.

I struggling with that... I tried serveral approaches on my machine. Nothing worked. Heres my current testscript. And it doesn't matter if I copy the file or if I hit Enter and copy just the filename. In all cases the umlaut will not be translated.

The script itself has the file encoding utf-8. As example I added text in normal, raw and unicode. They are replaced like expected. Just my copied filename not...

#### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# clean file name. Removes spaces, umlaute and do all lowercase

import pyperclip as pc
import locale 
import platform
import unicodedata

print(platform.system())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding()) # MacOS Big Sur = UTF-8


text = pc.paste()
print('\n## Copy paste things')
print('copy paste text: ', text)
print('type(text): ', type(text))
print('repr(text): ', repr(text))

test_dict = {
        'copypaste' : text,
        'normal' : 'ästhetik',
        'raw' : r'ästhetik',
        'unicode' : u'ästhetik'
        }
#text = text.replace(' ', '-')
print('\n## Original')
for k in test_dict.keys(): 
    print(k, ': ', test_dict[k])

print('\n## Replaces normal')
for k in test_dict.keys(): 
    print(k, ': ', test_dict[k].replace('ä', 'ae'))

print('\n## Replaces raw')
for k in test_dict.keys(): 
    print(k, ': ', test_dict[k].replace(r'ä', r'ae'))


print('\n## Replaces unicode')
for k in test_dict.keys(): 
    print(k, ': ', test_dict[k].replace(u'ä', u'ae'))
```

And here is the accoring output. As you can the on 'copypaste' the name is still 'ästhetik.png'

#### Output

```
## Machine settings
Darwin
UTF-8

## Copy paste things
copy paste text:  ästhetik.png
type(text):  <class 'str'>
repr(text):  'ästhetik.png'

## Original
copypaste :  ästhetik.png
normal :  ästhetik
raw :  ästhetik
unicode :  ästhetik

## Replaces normal
copypaste :  ästhetik.png
normal :  aesthetik
raw :  aesthetik
unicode :  aesthetik

## Replaces raw
copypaste :  ästhetik.png
normal :  aesthetik
raw :  aesthetik
unicode :  aesthetik

## Replaces unicode
copypaste :  ästhetik.png
normal :  aesthetik
raw :  aesthetik
unicode :  aesthetik
```

Comment: I would use iconv.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that with iconv. The input format ist UTF-8 and the output as well.. how woud you do that @RichardBarber ?